# Elegant check for std::find "not found" condition

Tags: c++

I am using most common way to search for some particular object in a small list:

```
iterator=std::find(begin, end, whatToFind);
```

If std::find does not find the element, it will return iterator at the end of the container, so the most common and suggested on SO way is:

```
if (iterator != end) {
    found 
} else {
    not found
}
```

But what if the element I am looking for IS at the end? Or maybe it is a list, containing ONLY the element I am looking for? Do I really need to manually check for these conditions or there is some sort of flag (which I don't know), which definitely marks the not_found case? 
Thank you.

Comment: `end` isn't an iterator to the last element in the search range.

Comment: There's no further element pointed to by `end()`!

Comment: Please notice: Ranges in C/C++ usually include the first element and exclude the last. Mathematically [first, last).

Comment: Thank you all for replies. This was confusing for me because my operator overloading somehow not triggered, thus resulting in "not found".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the searching item is at the end of the list (container) then the iterator is not referring to the `end()`. The iterator `end()` is a reserved (placeholder) iterator, the next one after your last item. However it doesn't apply for `begin()` which is really refers to the first item inside the container. Generally in C++ ranges are in this form [begin, end).

[image]

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the
>   container. This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it
>   results in undefined behavior. [†](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end)

Answer (score 3):

> But what if the element I am looking for IS at the end?

It cannot be. The end, (i.e. the iterator returned by `end()`) does not point to a valid element.  The last element (if there are more than zero elements) in the container is the one pointed at by the iterator *preceding* `end()`.

> Or maybe it is a list, containing ONLY the element I am looking for?

Then `find` will not return `end`. It will return `begin`.  Which, in that case, directly precedes `end`.

Answer (score 3):

`end()` does not point to a valid element (it points to one past the last element). Therefore there is no ambiguity.